# AWS S3 upload via presigned url returns 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to `AWS s3` by issuing a **PUT request** to the pre-signed URL. I have configured CORS on the s3 dashboard.

React code

```
  const submit = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/upload");
    console.log(response.data);
    const upload = await axios.put(response.data.url, file, {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": file.type
      }
    });
  };
```

Node.js code

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretAccessKey
});
app.get("/api/upload", (req, res) => {
  const key = `${uuid()}.jpeg`;
  s3.getSignedUrl(
    "putObject",
    {
      Bucket: "bucket-name",
      ContentType: "image/jpeg",
      Key: key
    },
    (err, url) => {
      res.status(200).json({ key, url });
    }
  );
});
```

When I try to make `PUT` request to the pre-signed URL I get the next error:

> PUT
>   https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/dd7eb480-9115-11e9-bb14-75395bf4d226?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAZPROFMOUP5TZZOIM&Content-Type=%2A&Expires=1560786770&Signature=c2ap3CcLKj%2FUD8yHtiHTNTnWJT4%3D
>   400 (Bad Request) createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error:
>   Request failed with status code 400
>       at createError (createError.js:17)
>       at settle (settle.js:19)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)

Comment: `400 Bad Request` has several causes.  You'll need to capture the accompanying response body for an explanation.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I have the same problem

Comment: As @Michael-sqlbot pointed out, looking at the response body did the trick. I was getting an "AuthorizationQueryParametersError".

Comment: for me same error was there, it solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56290480/9370941)

Answer (score 1):

I was attempting using a presigned URL and got the 400 Bad Request similar to above, but in Angular. It would send the OPTIONS preflight request and return 200, then send the PUT request and return 400. I tested with Postman and Curl and they both worked fine.

I eventually narrowed it down to the bearer token that was being received by the OPTIONS call, then set on the PUT request by an Interceptor:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        const user = this.authService.getCurrentUser();

        if (user && user.token) {
            const cloned = req.clone({
                // This line adds the bearer token to every request, but this causes problems with AWS Presigned URLs which aren't supposed to contain bearer tokens.
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + user.token)
            });

            return next.handle(cloned).pipe(tap(() => { }, (err: any) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (err.status === 401) {
                        this.dialog.closeAll();
                        this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
                    }
                }
            }));

        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to create s3 instance replace region with the region of your bucket:

```
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  accessKeyId: keys.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: keys.secretAccessKey
});
```